# Dealing with URI after $dispatcher->forward() execution

Tags: php, dispatcher, phalcon

I've set form submission URI to something like `'/register'` and in controller action `$dispatcher->forward()` to `'/profile'`. When submitting form, it forwards to the right page, but URI shown in browser is `'/register'`. Is there a way to set URI to those defined in `$dispatcher->forward()` method and not in form action?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `redirect` method.

So in your controller you could do:

```
public function registerAction()
{
    $this->view->disable();

    if ($this->request->isPost()) {

        // Here is where you process the POST and check the user

        if ($user) {

            // Valid user
            $this->flash->success('OK');
            return $this->response->redirect('profile');

        } else {

            $this->flash->error('Oops! Something went wrong.');

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please look at the diff before approving a suggest edit! http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1633924

Comment: I have and it was not allowing me to approve the suggested edit so I edited my post with the suggested edit - which is correct btw.